# Why did the movie depart from the book when Harry broke the Elder Wand?

Tags: harry-potter, adaptation-comparison, deathly-hallows

Looking for an out-of-universe answer. The Elder Wand is such a significant artifact, in that it is an extremely powerful object as well as being one of the Deathly Hallows, and so central to the story line. So, why was its destruction written in to the movie when it didn't happen in the book? Was it Rowling's idea to alter its fate for the movie or did the idea come from someone else, and why?

Comment: I closed this because I assumed the accepted “There isn’t a reason” answer on the duplicate was the case. Turns out @Slytherincess has a better answer, which she’s just posted on the original. :)